# height of table row not changing

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a table with different types of rows but i am unable to change the height and width of the 1st row below header row. how can i change it?
i tried setting height but it did not make any difference, the height of the code is changing only according to the font-size.

HTML code:

```
    <div class="table">
      <table class="api">
        <tbody>
          <tr class="tableHeader">
            <th class="columNo">#</th>
            <th class="name">Name</th>
            <th class="last">Last</th>
            <th class="buySell">Buy/Sell Price</th>
            <th class="volume">volume</th>
            <th class="baseunit">base_unit</th>
          </tr>

          <tr height="50px" class="dataRow">
            <td class="columNo">#</td>
            <td class="name">Name</td>
            <td class="last">Last</td>
            <td class="buySell">Buy/Sell Price</td>
            <td class="volume">volume</td>
            <td class="baseunit">base_unit</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

CSS code:

```
.table{
  margin-left: 6em;
}

.tableHeader{
  color: grey;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0;
  width: 2em;
  height: 1em;
  /* letter-spacing: 4px; */
}

.columNo{
  margin: 3em 7em;
  padding: 2em;
}

.name{
  margin: 3em 7em;
  padding: 3em;
}

.last{
  margin: 3em 7em;
  padding: 3em;
}

.buySell{
  margin: 3em 15em;
  margin-right: 16em;
  padding: 3em;
}

.volume{
  margin: 1em 7em;
  padding: 3em;
}

.baseunit{
  margin: 3em 7em;
  padding: 3em;
}

.dataRow{
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-left: 6em;
  margin-top: 0;
  background-color: #393e46;
  line-height: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0;
}
```

[image: What i am getting in my code]

[image: what i want]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The height of your row is being dictated by the padding and margin you have specified for the cells, because you are trying to specify a height for the row that is lower/smaller than the one you are getting from those. Try to set the height to some value like 400px and you'll see the effect. To get to the height that you want you might not need to individually set those margins and paddings for the cells individually.